# "Warning: ?Blood Msg? ..."

Tags: dark-souls

So I recently found this message in Dark Souls. It was definitely left by a player, since it doesn't have the developer message icon, yet it does not follow the available options when using an orange guidance soapstone.

I have also seen: "Try: Wings" and might have missed a handful others that don't match any template. What happened here?

[image: screenshot, click to enlarge]
<sub>click to open a larger version</sub>

Note that I'm playing the German Version, so the screen actually reads: "Achtung: ?BloodMsg? ..."

Comment: Is this on console or PC?

Comment: @Ben pc. I remember reading that the messages are shared across platforms somewhere so I thought it was irrelevant....

Comment: "Try: Wings" is legit AFAIK, wings are in the body part menu. Probably intended to share hints about which part of a boss to hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly *could* have been placed by a cheater, if they can hack the Dark Souls server. Everyone needs to google the divide between server and client side in an online game, because it is too tedious to go through what is possible for cheating and what is not. Suffice it to say the client logs (and the server saves without checking) the X,Y,Z coordinates of the message, so a cheater running a noclip could place a floating message off a cliff (I've seen this in Undead Burg, among other places), but the server is what gives you the options on what you can write (note you have to connect before selecting your templates).

These messages are a result of unimplemented or poorly implemented translation when region lock was removed in January 2015. I started seeing them the day after it was removed. The problem language here is likely Japanese, as it is extremely different from European languages, and difficult to translate one to the other. As Dark Souls was built with region lock, there is probably a lot of buried code that was missed for translation. I've actually seen that message (leveling a new character, my first is now too high a level for PvP it seems). Note where it is: it is in front of the boards the Hollow Warrior hides behind to break through and ambush, so you're looking at a warning for the ambush. Try:Wings is always written by a cliff, so it's yet more of those incredibly witty and not at all old Try Jumping messages.

Comment: Just a note on your first paragraph - Dark Souls 1 does not have servers. It's peer-to-peer via UPnP.

Answer (score 2):

If the message does not match ones you can create yourself, it was placed by a a cheater.

Comment: That, or it is a glitch in the game's code. ?BloodMsg? is almost certainly a variable for the actual text of the message in code to my programmer eyes, and the PC version of *Dark Souls* infamously has so little enforced consistency and anti-cheat software that you can create weapons with entirely custom effects (instantly Curse upon hit) and use them on other players. I am not completely up-to-date on cheater shenanigans, but this would definitely be par for the course for them.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an untranslated language string placeholder.